# passing arguments python script

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to know haw can I pass these files as arguments in a py file, and construct dataframe from these files

```
pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Demonstrator/Downloads/file1.csv',delimiter=';', parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format = True)
df_energy2=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Demonstrator/Downloads/file2.csv', delimiter=';', parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format = True)
```

Thank you

Comment: Eh? Do you want to *accept* the filenames as command-line arguments? Asking how to *pass* them (ie. how to specify them as command-line arguments) requires considerably more context (are you calling one Python script from another Python script? If so, how?)

Comment: ...if you mean to ask how to *accept* command-line arguments, see [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html), or [the argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing arguments is simple. You can have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

The most easiest way to pass argument to a python script is by adding these line to you python script and modifying them as per need:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) != 2 # here I am expecting only one commandline agrument
        print("USAGE: <Scriptname> <commandlineargument>")

        sys.exit(1)
    commandlineValue = sys.argv[1] # sys.argv[0] contains the file name you are running
    # Do what ever you want to do with the commandlineValue, it will just print it
    print ("CommandlineValue Passed is : {}".format(commandlineValue))
```